# Should I be concerned that my cat's insulin's cloudy - and how do I tell if this is ok?

Tags: cats

When I opened up the insulin I noticed that it was cloudy or milky and not clear. I did not want to give my 11 year old cat the insulin unless I could find some information that it was okay. I went online and I found a message "not to give your cat the insulin and to check for any particles in the bottom of the bottle". I looked and when I turned the bottle upside down I could see a milky substance coming down but no particles such as clumping, crystals or pieces. I did read another article that it was okay to skip a dose.  I did not give the insulin to my cat in case the bottle was contaminated.

The next morning, I called my vet and the vet assistant told me the one that she had was cloudy too and she thinks it would be okay.  That was not good enough for me I needed more than "I think it would be okay". I went back online and looked up the brand name, Prozinc and found that all of this brand of insulin is normally  "Cloudy" and not "Clear". Then I knew that the insulin was okay and I was able to calm myself down and give my cat his morning insulin. They should of added this information on the bottle so I could of read that this brand of insulin is cloudy instead of causing me to panic thinking that I could of killed my boy if I did not do my research.

Comment: What exactly is your question please? For me it seems, you gave the guide yourself: search for information from the manufacturer...

Comment: I've adjusted your title a bit. A guide for "everything" is a little broad *but* we're happy to accept and try to answer specific questions.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a vet, but my dad's taking insulin and I know for a fact there's *different types* of [insulin](https://www.diabetes.org.sg/about-diabetes/several-types-of-insulin-available/). And I know that the 'longer' acting versions have [additions to them that make them cloudy](https://www.healthlinkbc.ca/health-topics/types-insulin#:%7E:text=Intermediate-%20and%20long-acting%20insulins,the%20bottom%20of%20the%20vial.).

Looking at Prozinc, it's a long acting insulin and might be [cloudy by nature](https://www.wedgewoodpharmacy.com/learning-center/professional-monographs/protamine-zinc-insulin-for-veterinary-use.html#:%7E:text=Protamine%20zinc%20insulin%20(PZI)%20is,made%20with%20human%20recombinant%20insulin.). [Googling for Prozinc appearance](https://www.google.com/search?q=Prozinc%20appearance) gives us a [product information PDF](https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/documents/product-information/prozinc-epar-product-information_en.pdf) which describes it as:

> **3. PHARMACEUTICAL FORM**
> Suspension for injection.
> Cloudy, white, aqueous suspension

*Appearance of different types of insulin may vary*, but in your case there's certainly cloudiness.

There *ought* to be a insert that covers these things too but from what I can tell, your insulin ought to look cloudy under normal circumstances.